# Threejs canvas doesn't resize into tag div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, three.js

I have put my tag canvas into a div, for Bootstrap layout, but the canvas is bigger than the div container and it doesn't resize itself to the div size. I can't understand what is the reason.
Live example: http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/

```
<div class="row">


<div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;" id="ThreeJS" data-toggle="context" data-target="#context-menu"></div>



<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>



</div>



#ThreeJS canvas {

position: static!important;
padding: 1px!important;
margin: 1px!important;
background-color: rgba(188, 188, 188, 0.44)!important;

 }
```

and this is my threejs code:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth-5, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-5;

    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.01, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    var r = 4, phi = Math.PI/4, theta = Math.PI/4;
    camera.position.set(r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.sin(theta),r*Math.sin(phi), r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.cos(theta));

    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    else
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    // CONTAINER
    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // EVENTS
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You set your renderer size (= your canvas) at (window.innerWidth-5)/(window.innerHeight-5), almost full page. First define `container` before `SCREEN_WIDTH` and `SCREEN_HEIGHT`, then replace them with :

```
var containerStyle = getComputedStyle(container,null);
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = parseInt(containerStyle.getPropertyValue('height')),
    SCREEN_WIDTH = parseInt(containerStyle.getPropertyValue('width'));
```

Same in `THREEx.WindowResize` function : find where height and width are defined, and replace them with those values.

Comment: Where are height and width defined in your example?

Comment: can I speak to you in chat? I need your help and I saw you are expert with three.js @Astrak

Comment: just discovering it since last months. this solution only is javascript. we could meet in javascript room, give me an hour @stefano

Comment: if you want add me on Skype, my nick is: felpone  @Astrak

Answer (score 0):

The reason of overflow is simple, you have given the canvas dimension to fill/cover the whole webpage (in your js code).

Your webpage has two columns layout that ratio is 8:4. Left side of your column (.col-sm-8) contains canvas HTML element. so, it can contain the wider element than it self. ( your js code has been declared `setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)`.

just implement this CSS to your code.

```
canvas{
width: 100%
height: <set as you want eg. 50% or 100% of its parent container>
}
```

This will help to fit your canvas.